# Dynamically merge tables in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've found several sources that appear to give me a solution to my need, but each one has come up short.  I think my solution is in using VBA UNION; however, I am a complete VBA noob, so I feel like I shooting in the dark.  Here is my need.

I have a worksheet with multiple tabs.
Each tab has the same headers for the first 10 columns.
I'd like a sheet that is a summary of the first 10 columns of all other sheets combined.

I thought if I made each sheet a table and named each, I could create a range of ranges and then just call that combined range on the summary tab. My thought is there a solution somewhere with Union here, but I don't know enough to know if that's right or not.

I need basically what this solution is, but rather than it running on a run command and doing a copy/paste, the result just needs to dynamically update. https://danwagner.co/how-to-combine-data-from-multiple-sheets-into-a-single-sheet/

As a Google Sheets user, this is super simple, but I have to use Excel for this. I feel like there must be a simple solution that I am just completely missing. In Sheets I'd have just done ={range1;range2;range3;etc} and I'd have had my output, if that helps someone get what I need.

Any help here is very much appreciated.

Comment: Easily done with [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d)

Comment: Perhaps I should also add that I'm on a Mac.  Anything with power Query would have to be done through VBA anyway since I can't use the Power Query Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Part of what is great about VBA is that it is an event-driven language, so you can set your code to run every time a cell is changed, workbook is saved, etc. instead of having to press a button. I recommend reading up to section 3.1 of [Excel VBA Events - An Easy Guide](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/) where it explains how you can use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    CombineDataFromAllSheets
End Sub
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks. I'll check that out and report back

Comment: So if I'm reading you right, are you suggesting I stick with the linked solution, but then create some events to handle the update?  If so, then I'd need 2 - one to wipe out the data already on the sheet and another to write the updated data.  While I can see this approach working, it feel overly complicated.  Is it not possible to combine the table ranges into a range (call it allData), then just use that range on the destination with =allData?